# Laravel Controller in Folder - Routing doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am putting my Controller called "LoginController" in a folder "login".

```
class LoginController extends BaseController{
    public $restful = true;
    //log in function
    public function Login(){

        // load the login page
        return View::make('login.login');

    }
}
```

In the routes, I give this:

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'login.LoginController@Login'));
```

Also tried

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'login\LoginController@Login')); 

Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'login\Login@login'));
```

None of the above seem to work, and give me Class does not exist error.
I am very dumbstruck with this error. Is the way I am accessing the controller in the "uses" correct? Do I need to do any additional things before I can get it to work?

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: Are you using laravel 3 or 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you should need is

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'LoginController@Login'));
```

Composer need to register this change in routes so dump-autoload composer

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

Also if you are using laravel 4,  then declaring restful controllers with

```
public $restful = true;
```

no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

this happens to me often, just to give a different answer that worked for me

> php artisan dump-autoload

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i had the same issue, i got my answer from                                              https://stackoverflow.com/a/31638718/2821049

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'login'], function(
{
    // Controllers Within The "App\Http\Controllers\login" Namespace
    Route::get('/','LoginController@login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In class you adds :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\folder;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

and in routes you call:

```
Route::get("admin/login","folder\class@NameFunctionInClass");
```

**Note: folder is the name folder class contains**