# How to put controller inside folder in laravel 5.1.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am new to laravel. I am trying to organise my controller by putting it inside a folder, but it doesn't seem to work.

My folder structure is like this:

```
/app
    /Http
        /Controllers
            /Admin
                ShowDashboard.php
```

My **ShowDashboard.php** file is like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ShowDashboard extends Controller {

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function init()
    {
        return 'Hi there!';
    }

}
```

My route is like this

```
Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\ShowDashboard@init');
```

When I tred to access **http://localhost:8000/admin** I get the following error:

> Class **App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ShowDashboard** does not exist

My autolaoder section:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is "App" folder missing in your folder structure - is this by mistake? If it is really missing in the structure that could be the reason

Comment: App is there i didn't mentioned, let me correct it.

Comment: I copied your code and it works, no idea what could be the reason for the error you are getting

Comment: I use php artisan server as my server, can that be a problem?

Comment: I don't think so. I can see "App" in your folder structure, but the name should be lowercase "app" - I guess that's just a typo. Check also your autoload section in composer.json - you should have there a mapping between 'App\\' namespace and 'app/' folder

Comment: Try also "composer dump-autoload"

Comment: dump-autoload doesn't helps. I posted my autload section.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to create a controller is to use the built in Laravel utility, Artisan. From a command prompt, browse to the directory your laravel project is located. For example: c:\development\htdocs\www.example.dev

At the prompt, type: **php artisan make:controller admin/showDashboard --plain**

This will generate a file named showDashboard.php within an admin directory under your controllers. The file will have the following code by default:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class showDashboard extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

Now that you have created your controller, add a method for init:

```
public function init()
{
    return 'Hi there!';
}
```

Your controller will now look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class showDashboard extends Controller
{
    public function init()
    {
        return 'Hi there!';
    }
}
```

Now, setup your route in your routes.php as follows:

```
route::get('admin', 'admin\showDashboard@init');
```

Save your work, and launch your page. When browsing to www.example.dev/admin you should see the message: Hi there!

I hope this helps!

Comment: I had exactly same, but didn't worked. Vote up for pointing best way to create route.:)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this was happening, but adding this in my route fixed it.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function()
{
    // Controllers Within The "App\Http\Controllers\Admin" Namespace

   Route::get('/admin','ShowAdminDashboard@index');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
php artisan make:controller Admin/ShowDashboardController
```

File name should be `ShowDashboardController.php`

Answer (score 1):

Everything is already explained but one more try can be done by
adding `controller` suffix to `showDashboard` and run `composer dump-autoload`.

I think then your controller will run.

Rename your controller **ShowDashboardController**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with what you posted. If you changed the namespace-to-folder mappings in composer.json, make sure you ran the 'composer dump-autoload' command.

Comment: I didn't made any changes to composer.json

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working.. **Try once**

created a file **ShowDashboard.php** in folder admin like  **app/http/controller**

now ,
**ShowDashboard.php**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ShowDashboard extends Controller {
   public function init()
    {
        return 'Hi there!';
    }

}
```

Added `Route::get('admin', 'admin\ShowDashboard@init');` in **routes.php**

and then run `composer update` on cmd..
Then run `http://localhost:8000/admin` .
it says.. **Hi there!**

Answer (score 0):

Create a new controller in subfolder, for example: `app/Http/Controllers/User/UserController.php`

In this controller, at the end of `namespace` must include folder name

Like this: `namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;`

The important thing is under namespace must write `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

finally in routes.php `Route::get ( '/user', 'User\UserController@login' );`

**UserController.php** contents:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function login() {
        return 'this login';
    }
}
```

**routes.php** contents:

```
Route::get ( '/user/login', 'User\UserController@login' );

// or use this
Route::group ( [
        'namespace' => 'User'
], function () {
    Route::get ( '/user/login', 'UserController@login' );
} );
```